# clientvalidation in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a required field validation with a customvalidator. However when the field is empty it still does a postback?

```
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <h3>
        CustomValidator ServerValidate Example</h3>
    <asp:Label ID="Message" Font-Name="Verdana" Font-Size="10pt" runat="server" />
    <p>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Text1" runat="server" Text="[Name:required]" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" ControlToValidate="Text1" ClientValidationFunction="ClientValidate"
            Display="Static" ErrorMessage="" ForeColor="green" Font-Name="verdana" Font-Size="10pt"
            runat="server" />
        <p>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Validate" OnClick="ValidateBtn_OnClick" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<script language="javascript">
    function ClientValidate(source, arguments) {
        alert(arguments.Value.length);
        if (arguments.Value != "[Name:required]" && arguments.Value.length > 0) {
            arguments.IsValid = true;
        } else {
            arguments.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Try using a `ValidationGroup` such as `ValidationGroup="MyValidationGroup"` on both the textbox & the Button. You could also have the `CausesValidation=true` attribute on the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `ValidateEmptyText="True"` to your CustomValidator tag

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.validateemptytext.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You should move your `<script>` tag containing the ClientValidate function to inside your `<html>` tags, preferably inside the `<body>` or `<head>` tags.